# How to use a loop with mutate dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question regarding a for-loop within R's dplyr. Imagine I have the following dataframe:

```
id <- c(rep(8, 9))
check <- c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(id, check)
df$count_x <- cumsum(df$check)
df$count_y <- NA
df$count_y[1] <- ifelse(df$check[1] == 0, 0, 1)
co <- df$count_y[1]
```

I want to fill the variable count_y based on an adjusted cumulative function below:

```
for (idx in 2:nrow(df)){
   if(df[idx, 2] == 1 & df[idx - 1, 2] == 0){
     co <- 1
     df[idx, 4] <- co 
   } else if (df[idx, 2] == 1 & df[idx - 1, 2] == 1){
     co <- co + 1
     df[idx, 4] <- co
   } else if (df[idx, 2] == 0){
     df[idx, 4] <- co
   } 
 }
```

The output of this for-loop is correct. However, in my current data set, I have many IDs, and using a for loop to iterate over the IDs will take too much time. I'm trying to use the functionality of dplyr to speed up the process.

```
id <- c(rep(8, 9))
check <- c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(id, check)
df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(count_x = cumsum(check),
                                 count_y = NA) %>% ungroup()
df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(count_y = replace(count_y, 1, ifelse(check[1] == 0, 0 , 1)))

count_n <- function(df){

  co <- df$count_y[1]

  for (idx in 2:nrow(df)){
     if(df[idx, 2] == 1 & df[idx - 1, 2] == 0){
       co <- 1
       df[idx, 4] <- co 
     } else if (df[idx, 2] == 1 & df[idx - 1, 2] == 1){
       co <- co + 1
       df[idx, 4] <- co
     } else if (df[idx, 2] == 0){
       df[idx, 4] <- co
     }
   }
 }
```

I want to use mutate to call the function count_n to fill count_y as described above. I'm aware that I'm passing just one variable, where I have to pass a data frame as the function relies on the column 'check' (col number 2) and 'count_y' (col number 4). I have tried multiple options (mutate_at, all, etc) but I couldn't make it to work. What can I do differently?

```
df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate_at(vars(count_y), ~count_n(.))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the perfect case to use `purrr::accumulate2()`.

`purrr::accumulate()` is often used to calculate conditional cumulative sums. It takes a function as the second argument. This function should have 2 arguments: the cumulative output `co`, and the currently evaluated value `x`.

`purrr::accumulate2()` allows us to use a second variable to iterate on, and here we use `lag(check)` as `lx`. The tricky part is that this second variable should be one item shorter, as it does not matter for the initial value.

Here is the code, matching your expected output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = structure(list(id = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), 
                    check = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
                    count_x = c(0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")


df %>% 
  mutate(
    count_y = accumulate2(check, lag(check)[-1], function(co, x, lx){
      case_when(
        x==0 ~ co,
        x==1 & lx==0 ~ 1,
        x==1 & lx==1 ~ co+1,
        TRUE ~ 999 #error value in case of unexpected input
      )
    })
  )
#>   id check count_x count_y
#> 1  8     0       0       0
#> 2  8     1       1       1
#> 3  8     1       2       2
#> 4  8     0       2       2
#> 5  8     0       2       2
#> 6  8     1       3       1
#> 7  8     0       3       1
#> 8  8     0       3       1
#> 9  8     0       3       1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This a way better and more elegant approach. I wasn't familiar with the accumulate2() function but it seems convenient. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that you weren't returning anything in your function. The second issue is that you don't need to use a mutate_at (or even a mutate as would be more appropriate for a single variable) when you're writing the function that modifies the entire tibble. The simplest way to get it working is adding a return statement and running it in line like so:

```
count_n <- function(df){
  
  co <- df$count_y[1]
  
  for (idx in 2:nrow(df)){
    if(df[idx, 2] == 1 & df[idx - 1, 2] == 0){
      co <- 1
      df[idx, 4] <- co 
    } else if (df[idx, 2] == 1 & df[idx - 1, 2] == 1){
      co <- co + 1
      df[idx, 4] <- co
    } else if (df[idx, 2] == 0){
      df[idx, 4] <- co
    }
  }
  
  return(df)
}

df %>% group_by(id) %>% count_n(.)
```

However, I would use Dan's answer above because it's much cleaner and has the advantage of not running a for loop, which isn't very "R". :)

Comment: I agree, Dan's answer is cleaner and more efficient compared to a for-loop. I wasn't familiar with the accumulate2() function yet. Anyway thanks for sharing!